# Is there any good book about mathematical physics?

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, textbook-recommendation

Is there any book that generally introduces/talks about mathematical physics as a whole and that emphasizes on mathematics, not physics?

Or is there no such single book because mathematical physics is really a general name for essentially disparate mathematical subjects that cover quantum mechanics, relativity, Hamiltonian systems, dynamical systems etc.?

Comment: Welcome @ale_7 to the Math Overflow. Your question is so wildly broad as it is interesting, therefore it will (in my humble opinion) hardly find an exhaustive and not opinion driven answer. However I'll try to do something below.

Comment: Here's what they have to say about the differences between mathematical and theoretical physics on Physics.SE: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/56293/

Comment: Courant and Hilbert, Methods of Mathematical Physics.

Comment: @BenMcKay I don't think the OP intended the question to read "a book that generally introduces mathematical physics _as was understood in 1952_..." :-) (To be fair, I was very, very tempted to make the same comment.)

Comment: I think the question could be improved if you can give some example of what it means to have a book that "generally introduces [any subject] as a whole" in a mathematical way. My feeling is that most "introductory" mathematical books are deliberately narrowly focused so as to get through some basic ideas, and refrain from making the most general discussion of the whole of the subject. For example, there are many excellent classic texts in mathematical physics (Courant and Hilbert for one, Reed and Simon for another). But I wouldn't say any of them touches the subject "as a whole".

Comment: How about Thirring's 4 volume series: https://www.springer.com/series/647

Comment: The Reed Simon books.